# Difference between this.functoinName and functionName inside another function javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Why can't i use getName() from student class directly instead of this.getName()  ??

As per my understanding getName() is a public function which can be accessible from it child classes. Can someone add more about what exact difference it is making if i don't use this in this scenario. This might be a basic question from JAVAScript, As a beginner it is hard to understand the scenarion. Thanks for help in advance.

```js
class person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name=name;
  }
  getName(){
    return "Name of the person is "+ this.name;
  }
}

class student extends person{
  constructor(name,age){
     super(name);
     this.age=age;
   }
  getAge(){
     return "Age is "+ this.age;
   }
  getDetails(){
     return this.getName()+ ", "+ this.getAge();
   }
 }

var p1=new student("ram",21);
console.log(p1.getDetails());
```

Comment: `getName` is a property on the prototype object - it's not a standalone function, so it can't be called standalone like `getName()` unless you're doing something silly like `with(this)`.

Comment: This is the way JavaScript has been designed, that's it :-|

Comment: Actually class is a syntactical suguring for constructor function ( please read about this if you don't know ) and to access any property or function of constructor function inside it this is used, when you extends one class then properties of parent class will be accessible by child class but that doesn't means those properties are global they are part of child class and must be access by this ( will be used to refer the current instance )

Answer (score 0):

Read about the prototype chain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

In your case you could either call super.getName() or this.getName().

As you access something on an object, it will search for direct properties (ownProperties), if none exists with the name, it will look it up in the prototype. If still not found, it will look further down the next prototype in the chain, until it will reach the last prototype, probably Object.prototype.

Your chain will be p1.**proto** ==== student.prototype >>> p1.**proto**.**proto** === person.prototype >>> p1.**proto**.**proto**.**proto** === Object.prototype

When invoking a function somewhere on the chain the `this` reference will be the instance itself.